# Hiring Bitizens with Panna City Medicines as their dream job

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I've unlocked the Panna City Medicines way back in December 2013. I have added 18 residential levels with two vacant slots each to increase my chance of finding a Bitizen with Panna City Medicines dream job. It's been 5 weeks and I've never seen any... Do they exist or just uncommon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They don't exist yet, probably have to wait for a future update

Answer (score 0):

Yes I agree. On other sites Disney has commented on this issue and have stated that they are aware of the situation and plan to update soon.

Comment: How about a link to those sites?

Comment: Yes, a good reference would enhance the credibility of your Answer.